# Ajax request to xml file outside of TideSDK application

Tags: ajax, tidesdk

I have a TideSDK application that will be in the same folder as another folder with an xml file and some images and videos in it.

```
    [my application]
        -> application.app
        -> [data]
            -> data.xml
            -> image.jpg
```

Now I need to get the data in the xml file and also urls/filepath to the images/videos
Is this possible?

The application is working online without TideSDK by getting the data with ajax, so I'm trying to do it the same way here, but just changing the filepath to the xml.
I have tried to do this by hardcoding it, and using Ti.Filesystem.getFile(), but the result is always the same: pathToTheApplication/application.app/Contents/Resources/pathToTheApplication/data/data.xml.

So as you can see the second part of the url is correct, but it always starts from the Resources folder.

Is there any way to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use getFile(). Are you making sure you are passing an absolute path to the file as opposed to a relative path?